# How can i change the size of an array describing a function (leaving the function the same)?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, imaging, resampling

my problem is the following.

I have a series of arrays, representing an image.
Every array describes an x-row of a f(x,y,z). Every element of the array contains an integer (which rapresents the value of the voxel).

So, every element of a given array is an inspection point for the f(x,y,z) which returns the value of the function in a certain location.

What i need to do is to change the number of the *inspection points* in the three dimensions, whitout changing the dimensions of the axis.

So i would like to know if there is a method that obtains the line profile of the function for a given row, end allows to describe the same function with a different number of values.

For example:
given an array of 10 elements (integer or double or any other type of number), which describes an unknown function in a known interval, i want to obtain an array of different numerosity describing the same function in the same interval, but with a different resolution.

I would to know if there is tool that approximates the trend of the function starting from a series of values, and allow me to make a sort of resampling.

Thank you.

EDITED

Comment: Is your question how you can downsample values in an array? What would be your criteria for selection / elimination?

Comment: Pleas be more diligent when you describe your problem. I cannot understand it. Is f a function or a two dimensional array? What type have the `(1,2,3,4,5)` tuples?

Comment: Edited. I hope it's more clear now.
Thank for your suggestions.